# Reducing image size and layers in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, oraclelinux

I have Docker image layer stack that looks like this:

[image: Image layers]

My question is why did it add 400+ MBs on the last command alone and why there are two CMD commands ?

First CMD command comes from base image and second one is mine, I assumed that only mine CMD command will be present. I started from [this image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/oraclelinux/9-slim/images/sha256-8363ce227bea490538f3e1d64bc74f96f85b9266ec1adcbfab8478376964fa60?context=explore)  and added installation for specific python version and few additional tools.

Comment: That seems a little odd to me; I'd normally expect metadata commands like `CMD`, `USER`, _etc._ to create very small layers.  I also know BuildKit's layer handling is a little more sophicticated than "each Dockerfile line is a new layer".  Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: Can you provide a public example that we can inspect?